# How Can I receive messages from more than one named pipes?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, named-pipes, fifo

I have to use a fifo in my code.

I use sock to  accept new client. For each client I create new thread to send and receive message to him.

In the function of the thread I use fifo to send and receive messages also to another process and here is my code:

```
 int s_to_c=open(myfifo1,O_WRONLY);
 int c_to_s=open(myfifo2,O_RDONLY);

 char echoBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE];           
 int recvMsgSize; 

 for(;;)
 {   
     bzero(echoBuffer,RCVBUFSIZE);              
     read(c_to_s, echoBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE);  
     write(sock, echoBuffer, strlen(echoBuffer));
     bzero(echoBuffer,RCVBUFSIZE);

     read(sock, echoBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE);
     write(s_to_c,echoBuffer,strlen(echoBuffer));
}

close(c_to_s);
close(s_to_c);
close(sock);
```

And on the other side (The other process) my code:

```
int s_to_c=open(myfifo1,O_RDONLY);
int c_to_s=open(myfifo2,O_WRONLY);

char echoBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE];     
int recvMsgSize;
for(;;)
{
    bzero(echoBuffer,RCVBUFSIZE);
    fgets(echoBuffer,RCVBUFSIZE,stdin);
    echoBuffer[strlen(echoBuffer)-1]='\0';

    write(c_to_s, echoBuffer, strlen(echoBuffer));

    bzero(echoBuffer,RCVBUFSIZE);

    read(s_to_c, echoBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE);
    printf("%s\n", echoBuffer);
}
```

My problem is in this process : `s_to_c` and `c_to_s` take always the value(3,4).

So the first client connect correctly sending and receiving his message.

But when the second connect the first client become disable.And the messages of the second client sends and receives to and from the two processes.

Can I have some help please.Should I have to use tags for example??

Comment: In your actual code, you *do* have error checking? And what values the file descriptors get are irrelevant, file descriptor `3` (for example) is not the same as file descriptor `3` in another process. That you always gets the same just means that you haven't used any other descriptor before you open the pipe.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean exactly.

My code execute correctly for the first client.

In the server I print the values :

sock=4.
s_to_c=6.
c_to_s=7.

In the process I have this values:

s_to_c=3.
c_to_s=4.

Comment: Like I said, the descriptor numbers are really irrelevant, don't worry about them.

Comment: My idea may be complexity and not professional. I want to open new window (New process)  in the server pc for each new client so I have to use socket between client an server.  And the fifi between the server code  and the New terminal window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) allows you to check the status of a file descriptor (in your case the ones connected to your pipes). When `select()` returns, it tells you which pipes have data to process. That way, you can monitor many pipes in the server process.

The client process will always use the file descriptors 3 and 4 for the pipes since those are the first free ones after the stdio (0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr). So that is correct.

If you see the combination of 3 and 4 on your server as well, then you have a bug in the code where you create the pipes, not in the place where you use them.

If you use Linux, there is an easy way to see what a file descriptor is connected to: Look into `/proc/PID/fd/` (replace PID with ID of the process that you want to examine) or use `lsof -n -p PID` (which shows a lot of other things as well like loaded shared libraries).

Comment: Sorry this isn't ehar I am looking for. New thread creates for each new client. Select can't help me in these case. I am thinging about tag for each tow side? Could this helps me?

Comment: Or maybe I have to make the values in the second process not equal to (3,4)